# Three way switch wiring problems (1 light, 2 switches)

Tags: wiring

I am installing a ceiling light that runs off of 2 switches. The ceiling box has 2 white and 2 black wires. Three are neutral and only the one black is hot.

I have tried every combination of the wires, Black to black, white to white and black with 2 whites etc.

At one point, the fixture lit up but would not turn off. I have a copper wire from the fixture grounded to the ceiling box. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to DIY! We'll need a little more information. Is this the only light controlled by those two switches? Could you attach a photo of the wires in the ceiling box? Could you also attach a photo showing the connections of the wires at the switches? (Don't disconnect any of them.)

Comment: 1 - **PICTURES** of the switch boxes and fixture box would help a lot. 2 - "off of 2 switches" - meaning what we (in the US) call a 3-way switch - i.e., either switch can turn the light on or off? 3 - "Three are neutral" is a guess, and likely incorrect. More likely is 1 neutral, 1 hot, 1 switched hot and 1??? 4 - Was there a previous fixture, and if so, any idea how it was connected?

Comment: Black is not neutral, ever, unless there's a major mistake. You have a "3-way" switch, and that involves "travelers" (white may not be neutral either) and depending on age there might also be a switch loop (again, white may not be neutral, and might be joined to a hot black.)

Comment: Can you *please* post photos of the insides of the switch and light boxes?